# Proving there are no rational cubic roots between two $f^3$ and $(f+1)^3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

Consider the difference between two consecutive positive cubes $f^3$ and $(f+1)^3$ is given by $3f^2 + 3f + 1$. If $f$ is a positive integer, there are no integer solutions for $\sqrt[3]{3f^2 + 3f + 1}$ unless $f=0$, as this directly follows from FLT.

I'm interested instead in the case where $f = \frac{a}{b}$ is not an integer but a rational number greater than one, and proving there are no rational cubic roots in this case. I don't think FLT applies as it is not integer, nor can I use rational root theorem. I think I have an outline of a proof that there are no rational solutions even in this case, but I am not sure if I'm approaching it correctly, so I'll outline it briefly here. First, we assume there is an irreducible rational solution $p/q$, then

$p^3 = q^3\left( \frac{3a^2}{b^2} + \frac{3a}{b} + 1 \right)$

As $p^3$ is an integer, then multiplication by integer $q^3$ must convert the RHS to an integer, so I think one can write that $q^3 = mb^2$ where $m$ is a positive whole number. It follows that

$p^3 = m(3a^2 + 3ab + b^2)$

But the bracketed term on the the RHS is an integer, so this implies that $p^3 = nm$. But this would mean that $p^3/q^3$ is not irreducible (common factor $m$), a contradiction to what we stated, suggesting there's no rational solution.

The problem is that even if this is correct, this wouldn't work in the case of $m=1$ in its current form. Is the logic of what I've done so far reasonable, and is there a way to better do this or patch the $m=1$ case?

Comment: I can definitely see why we must have that $q=1$ or else that $q^3=mb^2$ for some positive integer $m$ (at least, we can conclude that $m$ is positive if we further assume that $q$ is positive). I'm not seeing offhand how to rule out that $q=1,$ though. I also can't see off-hand how to patch the $m=1$ issue.

Comment: If q = 1 we're back to the integer case on RHS, and I think this also implies b = 1 so there's integers on LHS and FLT applies here

Comment: Your title doesn't seem to summarize the question you go on to consider.  Shouldn't it be "Proving that there are no rational cube roots of $(f+1)^3-f^3$ if $f$ is rational"?

Comment: Yes @AdamBailey - should I change it?

Comment: @DRG  Yes, editing your title to show what you are really asking would be helpful - eg to those who might be searching the site in future.

Answer (score 2):

If $\left(\frac{a}{b} + 1\right)^3 - \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^3 = \left(\frac{c}{d}\right)^3$ for some rational numbers $a/b$ and $c/d$, you can multiply everything by $b^3d^3$ to get integers,
$$
(ad + bd)^3 - (ad)^3 = (bc)^3
$$
thus but Fermat-Wiles theorem, we must have $bc = 0$ or $ad = 0$ or $(a + b)d = 0$. $b \neq 0$ and $d \neq 0$ so $a = 0$ (i.e. $f = a/b = 0$) or $a = -b$ (i.e. $f = -1$) or $c = 0$ i.e. $(f + 1)^3 = f^3$ which is impossible.

Comment: Note that the impossibility of $x^3+y^3=z^3$ in nonzero integers was proved long before Wiles' work.